# Assigning categories to a single band raster in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reclassify

I'm trying to assign bins to a raster containing values between -1 and 1 in GEE. The bins would be `0.41<x<0.60`, `0.61<x<0.80` for example. Is there a function for this?

The only function I can find is `image.remap` which works for individual values rather than ranges.

Comment: Let me understand, values between 0.41 and 0.6 would be in one category, and values between 0.61 and 0.8 in another? what about the rest?

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe That's correct- the map i'm trying to make uses the differenced normalised burn ratio, but I only want pixels to be displayed if they are burned. The bins denote different burn severities.

Comment: Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274762/creating-multilayered-classification-map-on-google-earth-engine/

Answer (score 3):

```js
var thresholds = ee.Image([0.4, 0.6, 0.8]);
var zones = image.lt(thresholds).reduce('sum');
Map.addLayer(zones, {min: 0, max: 3}, 'zones');
```